# How to add c element in sorted vector without using standard algorithms?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

My code does not work in some cases: when `c1` is `4`, it doesn't output anything, but it works for numbers greater than 9. Why is that?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
void insertfast(vector<int>&v, int c)
{
if (c >= v[v.size()-1])v.push_back(c);
if (c <= v[0])v.insert(v.begin(), c);
int min = 1;
int max = v.size();
while (v.size() != 9) {
    int i = (min + max) / 2;
    if (v[i - 1] <= c && c <= v[i])v.insert(v.begin() + i, c);
    if (v[i] <= c && c <= v[i + 1])v.insert(v.begin() + (i + 1), c);
    if (c < v[i])
        max = i;
    else
        min = i;
}
}
int main()
{
vector<int>v1 = { 2,5,9,22,44,55,88,777 };
int c1 = 4;

insertfast(v1, c1);

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    cout << v1[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: There are at least 4 points in your program where you want to halt (`return`) within the `insertfast()` function and you aren't doing so. Once you insert a number into the vector, your done, but *your program* doesn't know that. Tell it to `return` after inserting.

Comment: `while (v.size() != 9)` [Rubber Ducky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) wants to know why 9?

Comment: because vector contains 8 elements and +1 woud be 9

Comment: @koka https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)

Comment: so your `inserfast()` is designed to works only to add an element to a vector starting with 8 elements?

Comment: @max66 no , i mean in this case, but what shoud be written instead of (v.size() != 9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's just take a second to logically step through the code here, since I assume this is a homework question, it's important to understand how to do this. There are tools like debuggers that are used on larger projects and more difficult problems, but small logic errors like this happen all the time.

Ok, so `insertfast()` is a function to insert an `int` into a `vector<int>` in an ordered manner. The first thing you do is compare against the first and last elements of the vector.

```
if (c >= v[v.size() - 1]) 
    v.push_back(c); 
if (c <= v[0]) 
    v.insert(v.begin(), c);
```

We can only be one of these things, and if either are true we are done. So the best option here is to just `return` from the function, we don't care about doing anything else. We know that, but the program doesn't. It'll keep on comparing things we don't want to compare and bug out.

```
if (c >= v[v.size() - 1]) {
    v.push_back(c);
    return;
}
if (c <= v[0]) {
    v.insert(v.begin(), c);
    return;
}
```

What if both of these statements are false, and we are still in the function? We still need to figure where to insert this value, so we loop through the elements.

```
while (v.size() != 9)
```

This is a very poor conditional loop, since it will *only* work if we pass a vector of size 8 into the function. With your particular arithmetic, you essentially want to *loop until some value is added to the vector.* I recommend an unconditional loop (we are trying to be "fast" after all) aka an infinite loop, and explicitly return or break within the loop.

```
int min = 1;
int max = v.size();
while (1) {
    int i = (min + max) / 2;
    if (v[i - 1] <= c && c <= v[i]) {
        v.insert(v.begin() + i, c);
        return;
    }
    if (v[i] <= c && c <= v[i + 1]) {
        v.insert(v.begin() + (i + 1), c);
        return;
    }
    if (c < v[i])
        max = i;
    else
        min = i;
}
```

`break` instead of `return` will also work just fine here, since if you break out of this loop, the end of the function is hit and you just return anyways. So, we solved the problem just by rethinking the design and stepping through the code.

Answer (score 1):

You have two logic problems in your code:

1. For your test data in `insertfast()` function you step into `while()`, when you step into first `if (v[i - 1] <= c && c <= v[i])` you insert `4` value and in becomes `v[1]`, and you have step right after that into next `if (v[i] <= c && c <= v[i + 1])`, so you need to set second if as `else if`, like this:

   ```
   if (v[i - 1] <= c && c <= v[i])
   {
       v.insert(v.begin() + i, c);
   }
   else if (v[i] <= c && c <= v[i + 1])
   {
       v.insert(v.begin() + (i + 1), c);
   }
   ```
2. From the previous item your vector increased for 2 elements, so his size becomes `10`, and you had infinite loop `while (v.size() != 9)`, I think you can just do `break` to leave loop in case of success insert:

   ```
   if (v[i - 1] <= c && c <= v[i])
   {
       v.insert(v.begin() + i, c);
       break;
   }
   else if (v[i] <= c && c <= v[i + 1])
   {
       v.insert(v.begin() + (i + 1), c);
       break;
   }
   ```

There is no need to run loop further, if you have inserted element.
Actually 2nd item with `break` will fix and `else` missing problem, in case of insertion it will leave loop and won't be able to step into second if.